# one eclipse Indigo and two GWT SDK versions

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I decided to install GWT 1.5 in addition to installed GWT SDK 2.3; I've never had two GWT SDK on one IDE before... The question is... 
Won't the two SDKs conflict if I have them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can easily have multiple SDKs installed. You can select the one you want to use for your project in the project properties (In Eclipse: Google->Web Toolkit->Use specific SDK)

Comment: Emm... I just wanted to ask. I have Eclipse Indigo 3.7 installed; Is it OK for GWT SDK 1.5 to create gwt projects?

Comment: I'm not sure if the plugin Eclipse 3.7 is supported (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html lists versions up to 3.6), but if you got it running with SDK 2.3 you should be fine.You won't have to worry about any conflicts since a project will only use one.

Comment: I couldn't find any tips... There is less information about eclipse and 1.5 support; Should I install a specific eclipse for v 1.5 to have UI support?

Comment: Do you mean UIBinder support? That is only available for SDK versions 2.0 and up.

Comment: I mean "Design" mode support. So SDK 1.5 will help to compile only?

Comment: If you mean GWT Designer, I don't know since I never used that tool. On another note, although it's no problem to have multiple GWT SDKs installed, it's best to always use the latest version. As far as I know, code written for an older version most likely will still work if you switch the SDK to a newer version. Can I ask you why you want version 1.5 installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many. You can set the default GWT SDK in Preferences->Google->Web Toolkit or you can override this per project (Project->Properties-Libraries)